# What is it called when you have a span with more than two legs?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have a span $A \leftarrow C \rightarrow B$.  Can we have a span with three morphisms?  Can we add a morphism from $C \rightarrow D$?  What is this called?

Comment: In the special case where the maps are jointly monic,Freyd, Scedrov call the diagram a *table* (because it "tabulates" a relation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it a [multispan](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/multispan), though a multispan is an even more general concept than what you suggest.

*Off-topic:* Your question reminded me of a joke.

> - **Q:** What do you call a donkey with three legs?
> - **A:** A wonkey!